# Panache Entity - QuerySyntaxException unexpected token in panache entity during projection to DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I m trying to make a projection of my entities in Quarkus, but i m always getting an error `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:member`

Here is the Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "key_performance_indicator")
public class KeyPerformanceIndicator extends PanacheEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_member")
    public Member member;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_execution")
    public KpiValuationExecution kpiValuationExecution;
}
```

The DTO:

```
public class KpiResourceDTO {

private KpiIdentifier identifier;
private LocalDate timestamp;
private Double value;
private Set<MetricDTO> metrics;


public KpiResourceDTO(KpiIdentifier identifier,  Double value) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.value = value;
}
//getters,setters 
}
```

And the projection code:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("execution", execution);
params.put("user", member);
KeyPerformanceIndicator.find("member=:user and kpiValuationExecution=:execution",params).project(KpiResourceDTO.class).list();
```

After the execution of the projection on the last line i m getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: member near line 1, column 168 [SELECT new sk.KpiResourceDTO (identifier, value) FROM sk.KeyPerformanceIndicator WHERE member = ?1]
```

I have checked whether there is a NULL value within the mentioned entity. Tried different approaches to put the arguments for find method based on the documentation of [quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#query-parameters) version:

But without any sucess.

Can you please suggest me any steps to resolve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I have just resolved it. Member is JPQL keyword of course :/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).